# R - Relational Operators and Vectorization

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I have a vector of times when people scanned a badge.  I have another set of times that are 'measurement points'.

```
scans = structure(c(1388570120, 1388572119, 1388575229, 1388577402, 1388580457, 1388583364, 1388586817, 1388589929, 1388593054, 1388599025), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
points = as.POSIXct(9*3600,"UTC",origin="2014-01-01")+seq(0,10*3600,3600)
```

What I want to do is count how many `scans` are greater (or equal to) than `points`

```
sum(scans >= points[1])
#> [1] 10
```

This works one at a time and can easily be converted to a for loop or an lapply

```
lapply(points,function(x){sum(scans >= x)})
```

However, I cannot simply use `scans >= points` and get a list back where all of scans is compared to points element by element.

**Is there a way in R to compare one entire vector to each element of another vector without using a looping construct (so the result is identical to the `lapply` example above except possibly in structure)?**  What I actually have a list of vectors of scans which I'm already going to be `lapply`ing through and I'm hoping there's a way to avoid nested looping in R.

Comment: See if you could use `?findInterval`; at least in this example, see `length(scans) - findInterval(points, scans)`

Comment: @alexis_laz Interesting function, I'll have to play around with it some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
colSums(outer(scans,points,'>='))
```

I can't guarantee that the intermediate matrix would fit into memory though.

Comment: This is great!  ~5x faster on my machine than the lapply to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with the [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(scans)
dt2 = data.table(points)

dt1[dt2, on = .(scans >= points), .N, by = .EACHI]
#                  scans  N
# 1: 2014-01-01 09:00:00 10
# 2: 2014-01-01 10:00:00  9
# 3: 2014-01-01 11:00:00  8
# 4: 2014-01-01 12:00:00  6
# 5: 2014-01-01 13:00:00  5
# 6: 2014-01-01 14:00:00  4
# 7: 2014-01-01 15:00:00  3
# 8: 2014-01-01 16:00:00  2
# 9: 2014-01-01 17:00:00  1
#10: 2014-01-01 18:00:00  0
#11: 2014-01-01 19:00:00  0
```

This should be much more memory-efficient than building the full outer product.

Comment: Could I do this if I had 2 scans (entry and exit) and wanted to check if `points` was between?  I know how to extend the other answer.

Comment: There is still some work to be done for `.EACHI` to work for all cases, but for that case, you can do smth like `dt1[dt2, on = .(scan.start <= points, scan.end > points), .N, by = .EACHI]`. It won't yet work for all cases, but it might for yours if it has some good ordering properties. If it doesn't work, you can still do it, by adding an index to `dt2`, and grouping by it after the join.